# Logical address mapping in BtrFS

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I was trying to manually restore some file contents from my BtrFS drive by digging in a hex representation of the drive (xxd /dev/sd**).

The only way I see it could be done is to find a file_extent_item somewhere in the file tree. Then I would look up the logical address for the start of the extent data stored within this item and finally go to that offset to extract bytes. The problem I experienced is that such offsets do not fully correspond to the ones of the disk.

I made a script that would extract the logical address stored inside a metadata block header and then compare it to the address on the disk where I found that metadata block. Here are some results:

```
Phy. address: 150 0000h
Log. address: 150 0000h (match up)

Phy. address: 250 0000h
Log. address: 1D0 0000h (-80 0000h)

Phy. address: 824F C000h
Log. address: 41CF C000h (-4080 0000h)
```

I would like to understand just how these discrepancies occur and how to track them so it would be possible to locate data extents by their logical addresses that are given in file_extent_items. Does anybody know the answer to that mystery (or how to locate the file contents the other way if there is one :P)?

P.S. I can't look up files by their contents so the only way is to find them through btrfs_***_items.